# Autobuild on SVN commit

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2010

Currently we are using TortoiseSVN for version control. What I was looking for is a way to run build on svn commit. So whenever a developer tries to commit on svn, it should trigger build (MSBuild script?) and then if possible run all the unit tests before finalizing the commit. Would be great to get some tips or suggestions on this.

Platform info:
VS2010
TortoiseSVN
NUnit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [CruiseControl.net](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Welcome+to+CruiseControl.NET)

Comment: Isn't what CC.NET does is opposite to what I asked? Like you have a build server(or so) and once you commit and the build server detects changes in the trunk, it triggers the tasks. But what if I want to trigger tasks (build, test) from each individual developer pc before the commit?

Comment: Subversion does not support client-side pre-commit hooks.

Comment: Sorry, your question really wasn't all that clear. But the point of a build server is so programmers don't have to worry about having this infrastructure set up on their machine. But if you want to mimic the process in a quick and easy way, maybe just add a custom task to a msbuild script that does an svn commit with preconditions of build and test. I can't imagine developers liking this though.

Comment: ah sorry for the bad question. Hm thanks for the tips guess I will have to study about this stuff a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions for this. Wikipedia has a [list of build automation software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software) which may be useful.

I like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) a lot, but Hudson is a little Java-biased, so there may be better solutions out there for .NET.

EDIT: It seems the OP wants to run a local build before allowing the user to commit. I think this is a bad idea, since it basically makes committing a much more length operation. If there are issues with developers committing broken code, that is more a matter of policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). The professional edition is free (but supports only 20 build configurations). We built separate build configurations for each repository (A repository contains multiple applications - visual studio solutions) out of which two of them address your question: The first build configuration is called 'Continuous build', which gets triggered every time a developer commits something. The next build configuration is a 'Nightly builds' which is a scheduled to run every night (this is configurable in Teamcity). This build runs NUnit and validates all unit tests and also publishes the report into Teamcity portal. Hope this information helps.

Comment: Yeah we are already using TeamCity combined with YouTRACK. Pretty cool stuff to be honest.